# Creating a user through a nested resource if they don't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, nested-forms, nested-attributes

Thankyou for your continued support here. I have a form which I'm struggling to get my head around the best way to structure it.

I have a form to create a new Event and wish to list fields for a User, simple an Email & Name.

When the Event is created, the nested resource User should be created if it doesn't exist, or the user_id should be changed to the one that's in the User table. My App isn't using any Authentication so current_user isn't available. The App is to be used on the good will people typing in Names and Emails actually do belong to them.

Here's what I have so far..

**Event Model**

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :attendees, dependent: :destroy
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank
```

**User Model**

```
has_many :events, dependent: :destroy
```

**Event Controller # New**

```
@event = Event.new
@event.build_user (I assume this is working and is building the user)
```

**Event View # New**

```
<h2>Get Started</h2>

<%= simple_form_for @outing, multipart: true do |f| %>
<fieldset>
        <legend>Event Details</legend>
        <%= f.input :name, autofocus: true %>
        <%= f.label :chosen_date %>
        <%= f.text_field :chosen_date, start_year: Date.today.year, :"data-behaviour" => 'datepicker' %>
        <%= f.input :chosen_time, minute_step: 5 %>
        <%= f.input :description %>
    </fieldset>

    <%= render 'user_form', :user => @event.user %>

    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

**User_Form looks like this..**

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>About You</legend>
    <%= simple_fields_for user do |u| %>
    <%= u.name %>
    <%= u.email %>
    <% end %>
</fieldset>
```

I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it. I'd need some guidance in what to do on the Controller side for changing that user_id through the nested resource too.

I get an error currently which states..

```
undefined method `name' for #
```

Thanks in advance!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not provide the whole stacktrace which makes it hard to say anything definitive. that's why i gave a downvote for your question.

so here is my guess:

your user_form looks like this:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>About You</legend>
    <%= simple_fields_for user do |u| %>
    <%= u.name %>
    <%= u.email %>
    <% end %>
</fieldset>
```

it calls the method `name` and `email` on `u`. in this case, `u` is the object that `simple_fields_for` creates. it is a form-helper that allows you to create input fields, select boxes, etc. exactly as it's done in the `new` partial.

so instead of calling `u.name` it should be `u.input :name` and `u.input :email`.

Comment: Ah, how stupid of me. This is what working late and having man flu does to you. I can't believe my stupidity forgetting u.input :field